# mysqlbinlog not showing 'pseudo-SQL' comments for BINLOG statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, percona-server, mysqlbinlog

We are running Percona mysql server **5.7.36-39.1** and corresponding version of mysqlbinlog.

I'm running mysqlbinlog against a binlog file and position (taken from the output of `show master status;`) with `--verbose` and/or `--base64-output=DECODE-ROWS` options but im not seeing the expected pseudo-SQL output based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog-row-events.html

(note i have censored the actual BINLOG output)

```
# mysqlbinlog --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS --verbose --start-position 56871313 --stop-position 56871313 <path_to_bin_log>
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
```

```
# mysqlbinlog --verbose --start-position 56871313 --stop-position 56871313 /pdisk1/mysql/replication/master-bin.019473
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
#220211 16:23:41 server id 176422933  end_log_pos 123 CRC32 0x8ffe454f  Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.7.36-39-log created 220211 16:23:41
BINLOG '
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
'/*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
```

However i do see pseudo-SQL for other BINLOG statements in the same binlog file.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to decoding this BINLOG statement!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely because the binary logging format is set to `MIXED`. In this case, some statements could get logged in the statement-based and others in the row-based format, and only the latter allows outputting pseudo-SQL statements.